# Make DOM element reappear on page after hiding it using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-show

How to make a DOM div reappear with new parameters applied to it, like different color, different number of children elements; after `ng-show =false` hiding it from the page?
`ng-show = true` is one part, but how can i modify it before it reappears or while it is reappearing? Basically, that div contains

```
<div> ng-show="showdiv" ; ng-repeat="x in elements" </div>
```

and iam trying to make it reappear with a different set of elems from elements

Comment: `ng-show=true` is not it?

Comment: thanks i edited the question it was not complete

Comment: your questions is not clear. can you provide code sample for this?

Comment: oh ok i just did

Comment: Still not clear what is expected. Take a look at ngAnimate

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable in your controller where you store a boolean value. Set the `ng-show` to that variable. Now if you set this variable to `true`, the element reappears.

JS:

```
$scope.showDiv = false;
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-show="showDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add specific class to div which will change appearance of div:

HTML:

```
<div id="test">sample</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#test').addClass(class);
```

you can also use **toggleClass** if you want revert it after another change.

It's not a angular but it's jquery. Your question isn't quite explained. Describe more details (html/js) for further help.

Hope this will help you.